# End a script 1 second after the first scripts finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run an animation function after another function (`handleScreen`) has completed. The animation function will fade out parts of the page after 1 sec. I tried adding a `.promise` function but that doesn't seem to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/eqdk82ru/1/

```
handleScreen(mql).promise().done(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow");
     }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Not sure wht you are asking. You want $("#splash,#name").show(), setTimeout(function () {
    $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow")
}, 5000) to finish after 5 secs ??

Comment: @joyBlanks Sorry for the unclear question. I updated OP so hopefully it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use jquery [`Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object to resolve this:

> `handleScreen` creates a `$.Deferred` that will be passed to the animation function. A promise from this deferred is then returned.

```
function handleScreen(mql) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    mql.matches ? smallBlock(def) : largeBlock(def);
    return def.promise();
}
```

> The animation function marks the deferred as resolved once the animation finishes (using `TweenLite onComplete` argument on the last animation):

```
function largeBlock(def) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;
        TweenLite.set('.square', { visibility: 'visible' });
        var tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.fromTo('.l1', 2, { height: 0 }, { height: 227 });
        tl.fromTo('.l2', 3, { width: 0, }, { width: 445 });
        tl.fromTo('.l3', 2, { height: 0 }, { height: 227 });
        tl.fromTo('.l4', 3, { width: 0 }, { width: 445, onComplete: def.resolve });
        tl.timeScale(4);
    }, 600);
}
```

> fadeOut is executed once the deferred is done:

```
handleScreen(mql).done(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
            $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 1000);
   });
});
```

### Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g5f7pex3/1/

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach that addresses the problem in a different way than you were thinking:

```
var alreadyFaded = false;
function FadeSplash()
{
    if(alreadyFaded == false){
       //prevent this from running a second time
       alreadyFaded = true;
       $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow");
    }
}

$(function () {
    //do something

    //make the fade happen upon finishing if it hasn't already
    FadeSplash();
});


$(function () {
    //by default, the fade will happen after 5 seconds if FadeSplash()
    //wasn't already called by the above function.
    $("#splash,#name").show(), setTimeout(function () {
        FadeSplash();
    }, 5000)
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/tthhaft1/

Comment: I gave that a go. Right now the script isn't doing anything. https://jsfiddle.net/njqcryLm/  This is what needs to happen before the fade finishes. https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/ It's at the bottom after the minified stuff.

Comment: Try the JSFiddle link I just added and work backwards from there. The approach is working, so you'll just need to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I think I got it working. Just a quick question. Say I want to remove the timeout function for fadesplash and just have it fade one second, after the first code finishes. I'm not sure what to replace.

Comment: In the first JSFiddle function in my link, just replace the 2500 with 1000 (2.5 seconds to 1 second) in the setTimeout() block, and have that be the last thing called in your function.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really confused. Now the splash just fades before the animation can even being. https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/4/ (the code is at the bottom of the js panel)

Comment: Ideally you'd call FadeSplash() in a callback after TimelineLite finishes its animation, but it appears as if callbacks are only a feature of TimelineMax in my quick/lazy research. The alternative would be just trying to approximate the time the animation will complete. You can do so by deleting the current call to FadeSplash and adding a call at the end of handleScreen something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/7ffLzgfx/

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little so it's easier to look at. :) https://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/eqdk82ru/1/   I figure it's easier to try to add a check function. `handleScreen(mql).promise().done(function()` So that it'll check to see if the animation has run and if it has, it will fade out in 1sec. OP edited to hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't do it naturally. Long Answer: use an interval to check for a flag, also, there is no need for 2 document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var finished = false;
    SOME FUNCTION
    //Inside SOME FUNCTION do your stuff, and before returning or whatever it is doing:
    var intervalCheck = setInterval(function () {
        if (finished) {
            //Do your stuff you need to do after those 5 secs.
            clearInterval(intervalCheck);
        }
    }, 1000);

    $("#splash,#name").show(), setTimeout(function () {
        $("#name,#splash").fadeOut("slow")
        finished = true;
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I tried that but the script doesn't run now. https://jsfiddle.net/spkga15t/     This is what needs to happen before the fade finishes. https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/ It's at the bottom after the minified stuff.